# C — Directory exploration

Tags: c, arrays, directory

I want to dynamically populate an array of strings with file name and directory name that are inside the specified directory path.

According to you, is this the fastest implementation for this purpose?

If not, can you suggest an alternative implementation?

```
int exploreDirectory(const char *dirpath, char ***list, int *numItems) {
    DIR *dirstream = NULL;
    struct dirent *direntp = NULL;  
    size_t listSize = 5;

    errno = 0;
    if (!(dirstream = opendir(dirpath))) 
        return errno;       

    if (!((*list) = malloc(sizeof(char *) * listSize))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in list allocation for file list: dirpath=%s.\n", dirpath);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    *numItems = 0;

    while(1) {
        errno = 0;
        if (!(direntp = readdir(dirstream)))
            break;
        if (*numItems + 1 == listSize) {
            listSize *= 2;          
            if (!((*list) = realloc((*list), sizeof(char *) * listSize))) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error in list reallocation for file list: dirpath=%s.\n", dirpath);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        *numItems += 1;     
        (*list)[*numItems - 1] = stringDuplication(direntp->d_name);    
    }

    if (errno != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in readdir for file list: dirpath=%s.\n", dirpath);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (closedir(dirstream) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in closedir for file list: dirpath=%s.\n", dirpath);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    free(direntp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ftw() and nftw() are meant to do a file tree walk, descending directories.  The find command is based on nftw().   scandir() reads the contents of one directory.  I'm not completely sure which of these meets your needs, but they do what you've already coded very efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about scandir! ;-) Changed implementation: now based on scandir!

Comment: The idiom `pointer = realloc(pointer, size)` is a memory leak waiting to happen.  If the `realloc()` fails, it zaps the reference to the previously allocated memory.  Use `char **newlist = realloc((*list), sizeof(*list) * listSize);` and check `newlist != 0` before assigning to `*list`.

Comment: I also think `free(direntp);` is a recipe for trouble; the `closedir()` should take care of that memory.  Consult [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) in case of doubt.

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation based on scandir!

```
int exploreDirectory(const char *dirpath, char ***list, int *numItems) {
    struct dirent **direntList;
    int i;
    errno = 0;

    if ((*numItems = scandir(dirpath, &direntList, NULL, alphasort)) == -1)
        return errno;

    if (!((*list) = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (*numItems)))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in list allocation for file list: dirpath=%s.\n", dirpath);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < *numItems; i++) {
        (*list)[i] = stringDuplication(direntList[i]->d_name);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < *numItems; i++) {
        free(direntList[i]);
    }

    free(direntList);

    return 0;
}
```